# Problems linking against AFNetworking iOSOpenDev

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, logos

I'm trying to link a jailbreak tweak against AFNetworking written with iOSOpenDev but I am having compile issues. I'm getting a Match-O Linker error stating

`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:"_SecCertificateCopyData", referenced from:-[AFSecurityPolicy evaluateServerTrust:forDomain:] in AFSecurityPolicy.o`

along with about 40 other messages similar. In AFNetworking's code, it's referenced as

`[trustChain addObject:(__bridge_transfer NSData *)SecCertificateCopyData(certificate)];`

I'm compiling using `armv7` and against the iOS 8.1 SDK. The files for AFNetworking also have flags to allow ARC. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to link against `Security.framework`

Comment: While very short, it seems to be concise. Accepted.